# Erro 1776, Nível 16

Tags: sql-server

Estou criando um banco e esta mostrando esse erro quando vou criar a tabela disciplina, aonde eu quero fazer uma constraint com a tabela Coordenador.

> Mensagem 1776, Nível 16, Estado 0, Linha 56 Não existem chaves
> primárias ou candidatas na tabela de referência 'Coordenador' que
> correspondam à lista de colunas de referência na chave estrangeira
> 'FK_Disciplina'. Mensagem 1750, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 56 Não foi
> possível criar a restrição ou o índice. Consulte os erros anteriores.

Não estou conseguindo encontrar a onde posso estar errando.

```
CREATE DATABASE AC_02;
GO

USE AC_02
GO

CREATE TABLE Usuario(
  ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
  , Login VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE
  , Senha VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  , DtExpiracao DATETIME DEFAULT ('01/01/1900')
  , CONSTRAINT PK_Usuario PRIMARY KEY ( ID )
)
GO

CREATE TABLE Coordenador(
  ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
  , id_usuario INT NOT NULL 
  , Nome VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
  , Email VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE
  , Celular VARCHAR(15) UNIQUE
  , CONSTRAINT FK_Coordenador FOREIGN KEY ( id_usuario ) REFERENCES Usuario ( ID )
)
GO


CREATE TABLE Aluno(
  ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
  , id_usuario INT NOT NULL 
  , Nome VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
  , Email VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE
  , Celular VARCHAR(15) UNIQUE
  , RA VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
  , Foto VARCHAR(100) NULL
  , CONSTRAINT FK_Aluno FOREIGN KEY ( id_usuario ) REFERENCES Usuario ( ID )
)
GO

CREATE TABLE Professor(
   ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
  , id_usuario INT NOT NULL 
  , Nome VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
  , Email VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE
  , Celular VARCHAR(15) UNIQUE
  , Apelido VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  , CONSTRAINT FK_Professor FOREIGN KEY ( id_usuario ) REFERENCES Usuario ( ID )
)
GO


CREATE TABLE Disciplina(
  ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
  , Nome VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE
  , Data DATETIME DEFAULT(GETDATE())
  , Status VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT ('Aberta') CHECK(Status IN('Aberta', 'Fechada'))
  , PlanoDeEnsino VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL
  , CargaHoraria INT CHECK(CargaHoraria IN ('40', '80'))
  , Competencias VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
  , Habilidades VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
  , Ementa VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
  , ConteudoProgramatico VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
  , BibliografiaBasica VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
  , BibliografiaComplementar VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
  , PercentualPratico INT CHECK(PercentualPratico IN(0, 100))
  , PercentualTeorico INT CHECK(PercentualTeorico IN(0, 100))
  , idCoordenador INT NOT NULL
  , CONSTRAINT FK_Disciplina FOREIGN KEY ( idCoordenador ) REFERENCES Coordenador ( ID )
)
GO
```

Comment: Você definiu PRIMARY KEY apenas na tabela Usuario, faltou definir nas outras tabelas.

Answer (score 1):

Toda chave estrangeira é referenciada a uma chave primária. Você precisa definir ela nas suas tabelas. Apenas a tabela usuário possui. Todas as suas outras tabelas funcionam pois a chave estrangeira é da tabela Usuarios, mas como coordenador não possui, disciplina não faz a chave estrangeira.

Para criar a chave primária: `CONSTRAINT PK_identificacao PRIMARY KEY ( campo )`